# reload partial view in popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

i use a mvc devexpress
my problem is :
when i reload partialview in a modal popup  by ajax 
after that everything except partialview remove

,i want have popup that contain partialview 
and i can refresh partial view by click (button in popup) with ajax and popup up stay open after click and refresh partial view ,
i want just refresh partialview in popup and popup stay open :(

please help me
here is my code

```
@Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(
                            settings =>
                            {
                                settings.Name = "GetDatepopUp";
                                settings.PopupElementID = "GetDate";
                                settings.PopupAction = PopupAction.LeftMouseClick;
                                settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.CloseButton;

                                settings.Modal = true;
                                settings.ShowShadow = true;
                                settings.ShowFooter = false;
                                settings.ShowHeader = true;
                                settings.PopupAnimationType = PopupAnimationType.Slide;
                                settings.Width = 50;
                                settings.Height = 50;
                                settings.AllowDragging = false;
                                settings.EnableAnimation = true;
                                settings.ShowLoadingPanel = true;
                                settings.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
                                settings.SetContent(() =>
                                {
                       @Html.RenderPartial("CalenderContainerPartialView", "Message");
                                });

                            }).GetHtml()

  ***************************************************************
  @using (
  Ajax.BeginForm(
   "CalenderContainerPartialView",
   new AjaxOptions 
    { HttpMethod = "Post", 
      UpdateTargetId = "PartialToRefresh",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
    }
   ))
  { 
  @Html.TextBox("Name");
  @Html.DevExpress().Button(
                            settings =>
                            {
                                settings.Name = "chkfffff" ;
                                settings.Text = "test";
                                settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                            }).GetHtml()
  }
 <br />
 <div id="PartialToRefresh">
   @{Html.RenderPartial("Calender");}
 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you contact DX guys directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in PopupControl callbacks for this purpose.

Take a look at [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/PopupControl/LoadOnDemand) demo regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Alter

**`@Html.RenderPartial("CalenderContainerPartialView", "Message");`**

To

**`Html.RenderPartial("CalenderContainerPartialView", "Message");`**

Found in:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q353474